# What is the fastest way to solve this very difficult polynomial question?

Tags: polynomials

If $x^3 +3px^2 + 3qx + r = 0 $ has a double root, show that the double roots must be $\frac{pq - r}{2(q-p)^2}$

Now the solutions provide an extremely complicated proof, that involves letting the double root be $\alpha$, and then proceeding to do various substitutions and equating. Does anyone know of a method that is actually reasonable and simpler?

Answer (score 2):

Hint;if $a$ is the double roots of $f(x)$ then $$f(a)=0 ,f'(a)=0$$

Comment: I guess my main question is "does subbing the root **that is given** into these equations and finding them to be zero counts as a suitable proof"? Doesn't "show that" imply that you should find them from scratch, or maybe the definitions vary between different countries